# Box2D platformer: Why does horizontal movement stop jumping?

Tags: java, box2d, movement, platformer, control

I'm writing my sBox2D game character's movement code, but my implementation of *jumping* is failing:

When I press the Jump key, the character jumps OK. However, when I press jump and another key (like the left arrow key) at the same time, it kind of blocks the jump from happening.

I'm using `applyForceToCenter` and `setLinearVelocity` to move the character.

What could the problem be?

---

Here's how I've bound keys trigger movement:

```
// press W key (aka Up key or BTNup)
if (RHInput.isDown(RHInput.BTNup)) {

    if(rhcl.isPlayerOnGround()) {
        toniBody.applyForceToCenter(0, 100, true );
        System.out.println("Toni jumps");
    }
}

// press A key (aka Left key or BTNleft)
if (RHInput.isDown(RHInput.BTNleft)) {

    if(rhcl.isPlayerOnGround()) {
        toniBody.setLinearVelocity(-5, 0);
        System.out.println("Toni walks left");
    }
    else {
        toniBody.setLinearVelocity(-1, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setLinearVelocity` method *literally sets* the Box2D body's x- and y-velocities to the given values.

That means if the parameter for **x** is set, the character will begin moving horizontally. However, if the parameter for **y** is zero, the character will stop moving vertically.

To fix this, you could either

- pass the character's current y-velocity in the y-parameter, so it doesn't change to zero, or
- use the `applyForce` (`applyForceToCenter` in jBox2D apparently) method, just as you've done for jumping, which only adds to or subtracts from existing velocities, instead of directly setting them.

The `applyForce` method is probably a better choice here, since Box2D is designed with the assumption that *forces* are what causes dynamic bodies to move. This usually makes collisions stabler. (Directly setting velocities is usually just used for [kinematic bodies](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082973).)